# php find string pattern similar to name="username" name="password"

Tags: php, string, preg-match

i am trying to code dynamic form in which php can crate sql query from the given form input name, for exaple

```
<form name="f" method="post" action="#">
 <input type=text name="username">
 <input type=text name="email">
 <input type=text name="phone">
</form>
```

i want to extract patter name="value" and extract "value" from it..  i know i can use 
preg_match for this . but i am not sure how i can exact do this please help me. `

```
<?php
$subject = "<html><body><form name="f" method="post" action="#">
 <input type=text name="username">
 <input type=text name="email">
 <input type=text name="phone">
</form></html></body>";

$pattern = '/^def/'; // what patter should i use to extract only input type names
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

thank in advance

Comment: why you need this? you can get all values after submitting the form

Comment: i want to create dynamic sql query from forms  thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/name="([^"]+)"/mi', $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

FYI: getting inputs from html is not very good idea :)

Comment: thank you very much .. its working . actually i am trying extract names from very large html form.... to create sql